# Question on differential equation with initial condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Question is as follows:

A differential equation, in $(t, y)$ space, with initial condition as in the following:

$$y'(t) = -3t-y(t)\\ y(0)  = 1\tag{1}$$

Find the value of $n$ such that $y(t) = -3t-2e^{-t}+n$ is the solution of $\boldsymbol{(1)}$.

Then verify that such $y(t)$ actually solves $\boldsymbol{(1)}$.

My attempt:

I am pretty much confused after substituting $t= 0$ into  $y(t) = -3t-2e^{-t}+n$ to find $n =1$.

And then I got stuck of not know how to go on.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to solve the equation you just have to verify the solution.
$$y(t) = -3t-2e^{-t}+n$$

$$ t=0 \implies y(0)=1=-2+n \implies n=3$$

The rest of the problem is substitution to verify the answer.

Comment: O, that is such an insight! That makes the problem so much easier! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dy}{dt}+y=-3t$$ is a linear ODE
it integrating factor iss $I=e^t$. then
$$y(t)=e^{-t}\int -3t e^t dt+Ce^{-t}$$
You can integgrate by parts and find $C$ by using $y(0)=1$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Then accept my answer/ upvote.